# Issues with Scapy not working in script

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, scapy

I have installed Scapy on my OS 10.11.5 machine and have been playing around with it in the interactive mode while reading through some of the tutorials on their site (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/index.html) and it's working just fine.

I can run `sudo scapy` and then run the `sniff(count=5)` command and all works fine; it does a nice and pretty job printing the contents with `_.show()`. All works, except a weird message:

`WARNING: __del__: don't know how to close the file descriptor. Bugs ahead ! Please report this bug.`

But that's neither here nor there as all things work to properly play with the packets (I haven't tested sending anything while watching in Wireshark, but I guess that's a topic for another time).

Now... When I try to do the following code in a `.py` file, I get all kinds of issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *

def packet_calback(packet):
    print packet.show()


sniff(store=0, prn=packet_callback)
```

with a `sudo scapy.py`, I get the follow traceback:

```
#:./scapy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scapy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/Users/myuser/Desktop/scapy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named all
```

From what I see in the docs, this is the preferred method to getting it to work, but it doesn't here...

I have tried `import scapy` and then `scapy.sniff(...)` and `scapy.all.sniff(...)` but those don't work either.

Just for officialness:

```
$which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$python --version
Python 2.7.11

$/usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

I guess I also have 2 versions of Python installed.... But the same issues happen with both installs.

Help! Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... I'm an idiot...

Lesson to all! Don't name your file after a module you're importing! I know better than this and yet look at what I've done!!

Bah!!